# Copy-Item inconsistent behavior?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Consider this directory structure:

```
C:\temp\A\file.txt
C:\temp\B
```

If I run the command

```
Copy-Item "C:\temp\A" "C:\temp\B\A" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop
```

I have

```
C:\temp\A\file.txt
C:\temp\B\A\file.txt
```

If, starting from this new situation, I run the same command a second time, I end up with

```
C:\temp\A\file.txt
C:\temp\B\A\file.txt
C:\temp\B\A\A\file.txt
```

Why is the result different although I run the same command?

Answer (score 4):

In the first case the destination folder `C:\temp\B\A` doesn't exist, so `Copy-Item` creates the (missing) destination folder and copies the content of the source folder to it.

In the second case the destination folder already exists, so `Copy-Item` copies the entire source folder (including the folder itself) to the (existing) destination folder.

To avoid this behavior make sure the destination folder either does or does not exist before copying (depending on whether you want the source folder copied "to" the destination or "as" the destination). Use [`Test-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849776.aspx) to check for the existence of the destination and [`New-Item`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849795.aspx) to create a missing folder.

Comment: I came across this bug today as well (after having encountered it already a year ago...)